# reactor-core version 3.1 breaks existing code

Tags: project-reactor

The code below is from the book `Learning Spring Boot 2.0` by Greg Turnquist.  It runs with reactor-core version 3.0.7.  It won't compile with version 3.1.0 or later.  In 3.0.7 the `Mono.just().and()` method returns a  `Mono<reactor.util.function.Tuple2<T, T2>>`.  In 3.1.0 it returns a `Mono<Void>`.

This is a really bad, breaking change in a minor revision.  What do I need to do to make this code run under 3.1.0 and later?

```
Flux.just("alpha", "bravo", "charlie")
        .map(String::toUpperCase)
        .flatMap(s -> Flux.fromArray(s.split("")))
        .groupBy(String::toString)
        .sort((o1, o2) -> o1.key().compareTo(o2.key()))
        .flatMap(group -> Mono.just(group.key()).and(group.count()))
        .map(keyAndCount ->
                keyAndCount.getT1() + " => " + keyAndCount.getT2())
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post the answer for anyone else who runs into this.  Simply replace the call to `and()` with a call to `zipWith()`:

```
.flatMap(group -> Mono.just(group.key()).zipWith(group.count()))
```

It's very strange that the reactor team would make a breaking change in a minor revision.